# How to sync to a label with p4java

Tags: perforce, p4java

I've seen examples online of using Perforce's p4java api to sync a client workspace with the latest files. Eg:

```
public List<IFileSpec> sync(List<IFileSpec> fileSpecs,
                        boolean forceUpdate,
                        boolean noUpdate,
                        boolean clientBypass,
                        boolean serverBypass)
```

But how do I specify it to sync to a specific label? Eg, the equivalent of this at the command-line:

```
p4 sync @labelname
```

Is it perhaps via the alternate method that uses SyncOptions?

```
public List<IFileSpec> sync(List<IFileSpec> fileSpecs,
                        SyncOptions syncOpts)
```

I had a look at SyncOptions, but didn't see any way to specify a label in there.

Comment: Generally, a label is just a type of FileSpec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After advice above to look into the fileSpecs parameter, I discovered that this method worked for me:

```
List<IFileSpec> fileSpecsSet = 
    FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList("//path/to/project/...@labelname");
client.sync(fileSpecsSet, true, false, false, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

FileSpec which is an implementation of IFileSpec has a `label` field :

```
protected  String   label
```

and the following method :

```
 void   setLabel(String label)
      Set the label associated with this file spec.
```

taken from the following link :

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/p4java-javadoc/com/perforce/p4java/impl/generic/core/file/FileSpec.html

Comment: Ah ok, mentioning the FileSpec put me in the right direction. It turned out I could specify a label via a call to FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList("//path/to/project/...@labelname") and then I could feed this in as the first parameter to the sync(filespeclist, ...) method.